Having trouble setting <a href=""> on same page as <a id=""> so I can link from another page
I have a page with categories of PDF downloadable links. The categories are each named thus: <a ID="place_link_goes_to"> so they can be linked to from another page.
I assume I need to place a link to each them from the top of the page because the list I have on another page (a full https path ending in #place_link_goes_to) isn't going up anywhere but to the top of the page.
Now because I don't want the whole list of <a href="each_of_them"> to be seen, I made the text white and small. (This doesn't seem like the right way to do it, but nothing else is working so far.) Here's the series of links at the top of the page:
<a href="#directory">Homeowner Directory</a><a href="#Bylaws">Bylaws</a><a href="#ccrs">Covenants, Conditions, & Restrictions</a><a href="#financial_statements">Financial Statements</a><a href="#minutes">Board Meeting Minutes</a><a href="#sunbiz">Sunbiz Registrations</a>

Then each of the sections linked above have these coded names, e.g.:
<a id="directory">Homeowner Directory</a>

My thinking is that when I click on the full https path from another page that ends in #directory (e.g. https://example.com/login/documents#directory) it should go to the Homeowner Directory, but it doesn't. It just goes to the top of the page.
I hope what I'm doing wrong is simple and I should know better. Please point it out to me. Thank you!

Your next-to-the-last paragraph confused me.  The #tag is part of the URL, but it doesn't carry forward to the next page.  If you click on an href without the #tag, then it doesn't have a tag and will go to the top.

As @TimRoberts said above, your HTML file must have a<div id="directory">. Then, clicking on<a href="#directory">Homeowner Directory</a> will scroll to the "#directory" div.

Not sure what you mean. I do include the #tag with the URL in the full path link to the page. Isn't that what my sample link shows?

@Andrew a ? not a ?

@ld8 What I mean is an <a href="#hello"> will lead to a <div id="hello"> somewhere in the document. The id of the <a> doesn't interfere with the linking. It only deserves a sole purpose of organizing and managing with JavaScript. An <a href="#directory">Homeowner Directory</a> is the same as <a href="https://example.com/login/documents#directory"> as long as the HTML file the <a href="#directory"> is located in can be seen at https://example.com/login/documents.

They are behind a login wall because it is secure for a private community. So unfortunately, no. I would have to give you access to the whole website which I am not allowed to do. but I will try to think of a way I could write two temporary pages as examples.

@TimRoberts Here are two sample pages that I hope will help:
{https://crystalcovehoa.net/page-linked-from/}
{https://crystalcovehoa.net/documents-3/}

The link with the <a href= cannot be invisible.  That's what the user has to click.  That's what triggers the whole process.

@TimRoberts The link isn't invisible on the page the user clicks. A short version of it ([Bylaws]) is only invisible on the page where the links go to because I thought I had to have them on that page. Do I or don't I? I know I have to have the [Bylaws] but do I need the href link somewhere at the top of the page or elsewhere as well?

You do not need href links on the destination page.  You only need a tag with the correct #id.  Why would you think that?

For your nav linking method to work, it should look more like this.
navbar.html
<body>
   <a href="/info/#security">Security</a>
</body>

file that /info leads to
<body>
    a lot of stuff here ...
    <div id="security"></div>
</body>

Then, when the user clicks on the <a> in navbar.html, it will lead to /info/security and scroll all the way to where a tag with the id security is.

The {a href} links I'm referring to are not in a {navbar}. They're in a small list of "Important Documents" grouped on a sidebar that users can see once they're logged in to the Blog.

...But let's say I use your suggested style anyway. On the link to page, could I put
Security Group/div>
in order to name the group of PDFs to follow?

@ld8 Yeah, the navbar was just a simple example, but your design works similarly. I don't really get what you mean about the group of PDFs. The id tag does not move elements unless you use JavaScript to do so, but if you asked about the elements coming after the security section, the  tag will just move the user to the /info page, then scroll down all the way to where the <div id="security"></div> is at.

You could do either <div id="security"><h1>Security Group</h1>PDFs here...</div> or <div id="security">Security Group</div><p>...</p>, both will work.

I have found my solution. I should have said I was working on a WordPress site, and I just realized it was creating error links. Instead of <a id="bylaws">Bylaws</a>, when I inspected the page, I saw this: <a href=“http://<a href=“#bylaws”>Bylaws</a></a>. It's no wonder my links weren't working. So I found that I could create an anchor for each paragraph (a block in WP). The anchor for the group Bylaws is simply the word "bylaws" and WordPress automatically makes that #bylaws. When I tested it, the full link path https://example.com/documents#bylaws from the other page jumped right to it. There was no need for the series of small invisible links at the top of the page after all, and of course they would only be necessary if I were jumping from somewhere on the same page (such as what @Andrew thought must be a navbar). I'm sure everyone's help will be of use to others, and I'm very appreciative of your time and thoughts.
